# Creating a Transformation Pipeline in Three JS

Tags: javascript, three.js, transformation

I'm struggling to explain my problem, so please bear with me.

Is there a recommended way to re-apply the same transformations to an object in it's original shape for every frame, so that one can easily see the differences as the transforms changes the original object. In the pseudocode below, there is an "original object". In each frame, we apply the current transforms to the original object so we can see the differences.

```
UI Slider: Scale
UI Slider: Rotate
UI Slider: Position

For each frame {
  Original Object -> ApplyCurrentScale -> ApplyCurrentRotate -> ApplyCurrentPosition    
  Render New Object     
}
```

This way, as you change the transforms, in real time, you can watch the effect. I hope this makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the pattern to follow, after you extract the parameters from the sliders:

```
object.scale.set( s, s, s );

object.setRotationFromAxisAngle( axis, angle ); // r.59

object.position.set( x, y, z );

renderer.render( scene, camera );
```

Another way to set the rotation is:

```
object.rotation.y = angle;
```

three.js r.59